# Clickable image in GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, gridview

I want to add populate an listeview and every row should have an icon, of a pen showing it can be edited. 
But icon dosent show. :S

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TimeListView}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Day" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"  />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Time"  
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/editIcon.png" MouseUp="EditClick"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
```

prepared an fuction I will use on the image when mouseUp:

```
private void EditClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

The image is an quite large png which I want to autoscale later on, but thats another problem. :)

So why isnt it showing and is the mouseUp implementation ok?

Br

Comment: MouseUp is a bad event - better use MouseLeftButtonDown. And set fixed image size to see if it's being rendered

Comment: <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/editIcon.png" MouseUp="EditClick" Stretch="Fill" Width="40" Height="40"/> Dosent work. :(

Comment: Is column with image being generated or it's not being showed neither ?

Comment: is the "editIcon.png" in the same physical location as your executable?

Comment: Maybe this link will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841976/cant-add-image-to-wpf