# Can't add image to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I trying to add images to my WPF windows but I'm not able to. 
What I tried to do is to add `Source` to the Image Xaml and the image **does** display on the designer, but when I run the program the image is **not** displayed

```
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="0,0,0,64" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="355" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Airplane1.jpg"
 Grid.ColumnSpan="7"/>
```

Comment: Is the image a resource at your project

Comment: Yes. I also did include it in my project file just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you put your image at Resources an it's build action `Resource`, just try to put :

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="0,0,0,64" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="355" Source="/Resources/Airplane1.jpg"
 Grid.ColumnSpan="7"/>
```

[image]
Let me know if it won't work

Comment: I tried it. I won't work. It was the same problem: The image is shown on the design view but when I run the program the image disappears.

Comment: Are you sure your build action is Resource

Comment: What do you mean by build action?

Comment: Just select your image and you will find the build action

Comment: Thank you it worked. It was set to "none" but now when I set it to Resource it worked :)

Comment: @John.P Good to see that your problem was solved, but please [learn about the various build actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties) so you know why this solved your issue.